# Returning an int from a method, and text input in c#

Tags: c#, loops, text, input, return

I am simply very confused and could use some help. I dont really know what is going on with the return of num in numCheck method. My teacher said that it should look how it does now so what was returned and how can I use it? I am trying to make a program that asks for the answer to a math problem (e.g. 2 + 2) and if the users input is 4 it end but anything else it asks again. This should have taken 5 mins, I just dont understand what he meant. Thank you!

```
namespace readNumber
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              //should be a loop around this method call
              //for(......)
                numCheck();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int numCheck()
        {
            bool itWorked;
            int num;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a Number: ");
                string numSt = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(numSt);
                itWorked = int.TryParse(numSt, out num);

                if (itWorked)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Integer assigned: " + num);  
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It Failed");
                }
            }
            while (!itWorked);

            return num;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get most is "the name "num" does not exist in the current context" whenever I try to use num in the main program

Comment: Works for me with no errors. Is there any other code?

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong. The error should tell you what line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined any variable named `num` in your main.

In order to use the value returned from `checkNum()` you need to assign it to a variable like in the solution by @chouaib.

your main should be like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          int num;
          //should be a loop around this method call
          //for(......)
          num = numCheck();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that you had to declare num again in the main program, its working great now

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the question :

> what was returned and how can I use it?

The returned value `num` of the method `numCheck` is simply the number entered by the user, actually the method keeps looping until the user enters a *valid* number, than it *breaks* the `do-while` loop  and *returns* `num`.

Now, you can use `checkNum` as it is to acquire numbers from the user.
Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("What is 2+2 ?");
int ans = checkNum();

if(ans == 4)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Yes ! that is correct");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("No!, false answer");
}
```